# Property of the Dirac delta function definition

Tags: limits, exponential-function, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

The defining property of the Dirac delta function is that for any function $f(x)$:
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$$

The Dirac delta function can be expressed as:
$$\delta(x-a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{ip(x-a)}dp$$

How can we show that the latter expression possesses the property defined by the first equation? I.e. is there a proof of the following:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{ip(x-a)}dp dx=f(a)$$

Comment: Your "defining property" is not correct.  That equation holds only when $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the Dirac is a distribibution, not a function. Suppose $f$ is an absolutely integrable and piecewise continous function, then, using the Fourier transfom $\mathcal{F}$, the inversion property :

$$f(a) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(f)(x) \\ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-ipa}\int e^{ips}f(s)ds dp$$

With Fubini theorem, you have that :

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \int e^{ip(s-a)}f(s)ds dp$$

Comment: Perhaps state what properties $f$ must have for this to work.

Comment: Yes you are right, I wanted to make it "unformal". I edit my post.

Comment: @Gaetano But this gives a exp(ip*(a-x)) term instead of exp(ip*(x-a)). We can let p -> (-p), but then dp -> (-dp), so the condition from my question would still not be satisfied.

Comment: I edited my post, the sign in the Fourier transform is just a convention (you just need to keep the opposite when inversion).